# What is misconfigured in my https request in Goland

Tags: rest, go, http, https, request

I have a Go command that queries a service via Rest.
Up until now I used http and had no issues, but once I moved to https I'm getting a weird error that I'm not sure how to handle.

This is my function to create the client:

```
func getClient(url string, timeout time.Duration) *http.Client {
    const ConnectMaxWaitTime = 10 * time.Minute

    if strings.HasPrefix(url, "https") {
        cert := getCert()
        logHandler("protocol is https, got cert", "DEBUG")
        client := &http.Client{
            Timeout: timeout,
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout: ConnectMaxWaitTime,
                }).DialContext,
                TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                    InsecureSkipVerify:    true,
                    VerifyPeerCertificate: VerifyPeerCertificateAlt,
                    RootCAs:               cert,
                },
            },
        }
        return client
    } else {
        client := &http.Client{
            Timeout: timeout,
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout: ConnectMaxWaitTime,
                }).DialContext,
            },
        }
        return client
    }
}
```

You can see above both ways- https and http.
I have two types of error, usually at the end of the streamed output (which cuts short). It is either

> malformed chunked encoding

or

> tls: received record with version 967d when expecting version 303

What am I doing wrong/what it missing in Https client that causes this issue?
Important to mention that it only happens with large outputs and with remote servers. I'd like to understand what could be the issue even if it is not in my client side.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this particular code. This means it is either something which you don't show, some server side issue (nothing known about server) or some issue of the network (like some middlebox fiddling with the traffic). The current information are not sufficient to debug the problem.

Comment: I've added some information, I can add more, I'm just not sure what is relevant.

Comment: Both of these things are invalid responses from a server. Your code cannot cause these, the server or something between you and the server is at fault.